# Insert results in non-sequential IDs

Tags: postgresql

I have the following query:

```
INSERT INTO hosts (name, domain, ip)
SELECT name, domain, ip
FROM staging_hosts
ON CONFLICT (ip) DO UPDATE
SET name = excluded.name, domain = excluded.domain;
```

It works fine aside from the fact that the IDs in my "hosts" table are not being incremented sequentially. For example, I'll get the following new IDs after running this query:

```
114855
114859
114873
114977
117389
115326
```

The ID column on the hosts table is serial so I'm not sure why the IDs are incrementing sequentially.

Comment: Because a `serial sequence` is not guaranteed to be gap less. The sequence increments every time it is referred to in a command regardless of whether it is used or not. The `ON CONFLICT` 'burns' a number each time it does  an `UPDATE` instead of an `INSERT`, so you get a gap. Further each session gets its own cache of numbers, so if you have concurrent sessions they will use start at different place. For more info see [Sequnce](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createsequence.html), in particular the Notes section.

Comment: Oh okay that makes sense - is there a way to do this "upsert" operation to minimize gaps/and or avoid gaps entirely?

Comment: Why do you care about a "gap" ? These are just numbers to identify a row and that's it. For any other functionality of these numbers, you'd beter avoid the usage of a sequence.

Comment: You don't need to worry about the gaps. Simple as that. Just move on, there is nothing you need to "optimizer" here.

Comment: If you use `serial` you will get gaps, that is part of the package and is a by product of it being performant under load. If there is some statutory and/or business rule that requires no gaps then you will need some other process. Search on 'postgresql gap less sequence'. Just know the solutions depend on locking and are notably slower and/or may require retries.

Comment: If you are worried about hitting the 32 bit integer maximum, then for the small cost of 4 extra bytes, a bigint will count up to 9223372036854775807.

Comment: Yea my concern was hitting the 32 bit integer maximum. For as often as this table is getting updated, I'm trying to make the most use of every ID I can and I see it as unnecessary to skip several thousand IDs. I guess in the end I'll update the field to use bigint. Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on minimizing gaps, you could do that, with example tables included:

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  ip INT,
  name TEXT,
  UNIQUE(ip) );

CREATE TABLE staging (
  ip INT,
  name TEXT );

INSERT INTO foo (ip,name) VALUES (1,'hello'),(2,'abc'),(10,'world');
INSERT INTO staging VALUES (1,'byebye'),(2,'def'),(11,'world');

WITH s AS ( 
    SELECT COALESCE( foo.id, nextval('foo_id_seq'::regclass)) AS id, 
    staging.ip,staging.name
    FROM staging LEFT JOIN foo USING (ip))
INSERT INTO foo (id,ip,name) SELECT * FROM s
ON CONFLICT(id) DO UPDATE 
SET ip=excluded.ip, name=excluded.name;
```

COALESCE does not evaluate the second argument if it is not needed, which means it only calls nextval when required.